# Connect to Sql Server from php application deployed on Tomcat 8.0 server

Tags: php, sql-server, eclipse, tomcat

I have moved a php project from xampp to tomcat 8.0 server.
Now I am trying to connect to SQl Server 2012 from the php application which is deployed on tomcat (Eclipse IDE).
Please refer the following code:

```
<?php    
echo "Hello";
$serverName = "192.168.XX.XXX\sqlexpress,1433"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"XXXXX", "UID"=>"XXXXX",     "PWD"=>"XXXXX");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if($conn){
    echo "Done";
    echo $conn;
}
?>
```

The php code is printing Hello successfully. But am unable to establish a connection with the sql server.
The problem seems to be the driver file missing in Tomcat.
I have the following dll driver files: php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll and php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll

Where should I place these files in Tomcat or the php webapp, to get the sql server connection up and running.

Comment: Have you tried to add the extensions to your php.ini file?